# Anatomically Correct Catgirls

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, evolution

This is a submission for the 
[Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798])

Valentines days is coming up and what better way to celebrate that than worshiping our lord and savior Elongated Muskrat and his attempts to bring Catgirls into reality. now some characteristic of Catgirls are:

- slightly shorter than the average human
- have cat ears
- have a cat tail
- have cat like eyes (optional)
- keep characteristic of a 15-16 year old girl even as they reach into their 30s
- are extremely loyal (optional)

so what species would these Catgirls have evolved from and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?

Comment: Is the perpetual teenager look really necessary...?

Comment: "_what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?_" look in the mirror, look in your wallet.

Comment: @Azumentris well according to anime it is. but no not really

Comment: Why on earth would you elongate muskrats?

Comment: Do they get a verbal tic of converting every 'n' to 'ny'? the result could be a dealbreaker.

Comment: VTC: poor quality, as it's a copy-paste of other questions. Make this about your world or make it of use & interest to others! Always ask yourself: *what is the worldbuilding problem I need to solve?* before posting a query!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Horny  Men With Too Much Money**

Catgirls are straight up an anime abomination. They are not a natural thing. Instead, they’re created to satiate the weird fetish a lot of people have. So the pressure actually comes from Elongated Muskrat who is able to skirt the massive ethical and legal boundaries to human genetic engineering with his billions and gets catgirls made.

Then the catgirls are put to use as the ultimate twitch thots for extracting maximum income from thirsty dudes

Comment: yeah that sounds about right.